# Angualar - get API results but cant convert to JSON

Tags: angular

I eally need some help. So I am using Ionic and and JQuery to retrieve a tabe of results and I have 'hardcoded' a Json table for noew to make the drop down wor. However the results i get is in the format :

```
[
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "Jeffreys Bay",
        "ProvinceID": 1,
        "Longitude": 24.91667,
        "Latitude": -34.03333
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "Heidelberg",
        "ProvinceID": 3,
        "Longitude": 28.38418,
        "Latitude": -26.491
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "Name": "Springs",
        "ProvinceID": 3,
        "Longitude": 28.44278,
        "Latitude": -26.25472
    },
    {
        "Id": 4,
        "Name": "Boksburg",
        "ProvinceID": 3,
        "Longitude": 28.24097,
        "Latitude": -26.23259
    },
    {
        "Id": 5,
        "Name": "Benoni",
        "ProvinceID": 3,
        "Longitude": 28.32078,
        "Latitude": -26.18848
    },
    {
        "Id": 6,
        "Name": "Kempton Park",
        "ProvinceID": 3,
        "Longitude": 28.23333,
        "Latitude": -26.1
    },
    {
        "Id": 7,
        "Name": "Bedford View",
        "ProvinceID": 3,
        "Longitude": 28.13275,
        "Latitude": -26.17169
    },
    {
        "Id": 8,
        "Name": "Germiston",
        "ProvinceID": 3,
        "Longitude": 28.17078,
        "Latitude": -26.22587
    },
    {
        "Id": 9,
        "Name": "Edenvale",
        "ProvinceID": 3,
        "Longitude": 28.15247,
        "Latitude": -26.14095
    },
    {
        "Id": 10,
        "Name": "Krugersdorp",
        "ProvinceID": 3,
        "Longitude": 27.77515,
        "Latitude": -26.08577
    },
    {
        "Id": 11,
        "Name": "Randfontein",
        "ProvinceID": 3,
        "Longitude": 27.67869,
        "Latitude": -26.19915
    },
    {
        "Id": 12,
        "Name": "Roodepoort",
        "ProvinceID": 3,
        "Longitude": 27.90146,
        "Latitude": -26.12013
    },
    {
        "Id": 13,
        "Name": "Ruimsig",
        "ProvinceID": 3,
        "Longitude": 27.86338,
        "Latitude": -26.082
    },
    {
        "Id": 14,
        "Name": "Weltevreden Park",
        "ProvinceID": 3,
        "Longitude": 27.93076,
        "Latitude": -26.11942
    },
    {
        "Id": 15,
        "Name": "Florida",
        "ProvinceID": 3,
        "Longitude": 27.923,
        "Latitude": -26.175
    },
    {
        "Id": 16,
        "Name": "Randburg",
        "ProvinceID": 3,
        "Longitude": 28.00639,
        "Latitude": -26.09361
    },
    {
        "Id": 17,
        "Name": "Hondeydew",
        "ProvinceID": 3,
        "Longitude": 27.92563,
        "Latitude": -26.07915
    },
    {
        "Id": 18,
        "Name": "Sandton",
        "ProvinceID": 3,
        "Longitude": 28.0567,
        "Latitude": -26.10757
    },
    {
        "Id": 19,
        "Name": "Rivonia",
        "ProvinceID": 3,
        "Longitude": 28.05557,
        "Latitude": -26.04314
    },
    {
        "Id": 31,
        "Name": "Test 1 area",
        "ProvinceID": 1,
        "Longitude": 1,
        "Latitude": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": 32,
        "Name": "Test 2 area",
        "ProvinceID": 2,
        "Longitude": 2,
        "Latitude": 2
    },
    {
        "Id": 33,
        "Name": "Test Changed",
        "ProvinceID": 8,
        "Longitude": 0,
        "Latitude": 0
    },
    {
        "Id": 34,
        "Name": "Toets 2",
        "ProvinceID": 3,
        "Longitude": 0,
        "Latitude": 0
    },
    {
        "Id": 35,
        "Name": "Test2",
        "ProvinceID": 8,
        "Longitude": 0,
        "Latitude": 0
    },
    {
        "Id": 36,
        "Name": "Test3",
        "ProvinceID": 8,
        "Longitude": 0,
        "Latitude": 0
    },
    {
        "Id": 37,
        "Name": "Test4",
        "ProvinceID": 1,
        "Longitude": 0,
        "Latitude": 0
    },
    {
        "Id": 38,
        "Name": "Durban",
        "ProvinceID": 4,
        "Longitude": 31.05,
        "Latitude": -29.88333
    },
    {
        "Id": 39,
        "Name": "Test 4changed",
        "ProvinceID": 8,
        "Longitude": 0,
        "Latitude": 0
    },
    {
        "Id": 40,
        "Name": "New Area",
        "ProvinceID": 8,
        "Longitude": 0,
        "Latitude": 0
    },
    {
        "Id": 41,
        "Name": "Test plus",
        "ProvinceID": 2,
        "Longitude": 0,
        "Latitude": 0
    }
]
```

I know I am stupid but I sumply need a table

```
 this.items = [
       'Jeffreys Bay',
       'Heidelberg']
```

I tried every single method I could found but nothing works

Comment: `I tried every single method I could found but nothing works` ← Like what? Show us what you have tried and what is not working (include code)

Comment: are you trying to get all the names..?

Answer (score 1):

assume your hardcoded array is `hardcodedVals`

```
this.items  = hardcodedVals.map((item)=>item.Name)
```